# Load testing using Jmeter 5k users, website crashed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I was running 5K users on a website while load testing with Jmeter. It was taking too long time and my colleagues were not able to access the site. Then i stop the test. now the website is totally dead and is not accessible. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

You should either restart your browser and/or your entire system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I  would recommend you to try to understand how many users are going to use your system to set clear test objectives.

These articles I find useful:

[stress testing web applications with JMeter (Part 1)](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/17/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-1/)

[stress testing web applications with JMeter (part 2)](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/)

After you've set up your testing goals clearly follow [JMeter Performance Testing](http://www.guru99.com/jmeter-performance-testing.html) best practices steps.

Also I would recommend you  to get acquainted with [Load Testing Cloud](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/42674-what-is-blazemeter-s-load-testing-cloud-) - altentive cloud solution for running your .jmx tests instead of local run, which often associated with resource demand on your PC machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be use ramp up technique. This does not over load the server all at once but adds the load slowly till its reaches peak. This way it is easier to find the crash point.

Restarting the server will be a good way to bring up the application. Also check the server Logs.